# Microsoft Band Microphone

Tags: android, voice-recognition, microphone, voice, microsoft-band

I have an android application that uses the Microsoft band 2's sensors and displays the data processed.

The app works fine, I just want to add voice commands to the app via the microphone of the band. Is it possible?

I am using Microsoft Cognitive Services, the Speech Recognition Service to get the voice command, transform it to text then process it. I know that this API works fine with the android microphone, but I would like to know if it is possible to use the band's mic or maybe integrate Cortana.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Access to the microphone of the Band is not currently supported by Microsoft's SDK. But Band 2 does work with Cortana on Android. So, while I am not familiar with what Cortana for Android's capabilities are, your best bet is likely to see if there is a way to work with that application in some way.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that and tell you if it works. Thanks